# Gradle Android project dependency not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate from maven to Gradle for an Android project and I am facing the following issue: 
I have three projects i.e

```
root
- projlib
   build.gradle
- projA
   build.gradle
- projB
   build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

Basically what I want to achieve is that projB depends on projA and projlib. projlib is a lib folder that compiles and generates a lib(jar) file. projA is an Android Application and projB is another Android Application that needs to reference code in projA. Right now what I have added in the projB build.gradle file is

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':projlib')
   compile project(':projA')
}
```

So say if there's a class
FooProjLib in projlib and
FooProjA in projA

Then In projB I can do

```
FooProjLib foo = new FooProjLib
```

which works fine

but when I do

```
FooProjA foo = new FooProjA
```

Gradle gives me package projA does not exist, what I have observed is that both dependency is resolved but only the lib can be reference and not the apk.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: is projA being built as an Android Application or an Android Library (e.g., does it use `apply plugin 'android'` in the build file or `apply plugin 'android-library'`)? It has to be a library for this to work.

Comment: being built with 'android', an APK is generated in the build folder. Because it is an actual Android App, I cannot apply plugin 'android-library'. On the other hand projlib is being built with 'android-library'. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want. projA can't build an application (i.e. an APK) and also have other things depend on it. projB can only depend on projA if projA is an Android library, meaning in its build file you have this declaration:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

Of course, this means that projA won't build an APK, but will build an AAR instead.

If projA needs to also be an APK, you'll have to restructure things such that the common code that's in projA that projB also needs is moved out to a shared library. If both projects are similar, perhaps you could have just one module for them and use project flavors to differentiate them; it's hard to say whether this is a good approach without a lot more information.

Comment: The thing is the projB is a test Android Application that uses robotium dependency. It needs to reference to projA's code base to launch and run tests on projA Application. Is there a way to set the classpath in projB to include projA's code?

Comment: The test apps can be auto-generated now with the new tools, so you might find that you can just put your tests under /src/androidTest/java/ within projA, and that it will work.  There is some documentation here that talks about it: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing

Comment: That all said, if you end up rejiggering your layout, your tests will need to move accordingly (ie. to whichever project your views move to).